# Integrating django-haystack with django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-haystack

I would like to know, how I could use django-rest-framework to provide a paginated json result from a get request `q=thisterm`.

I understand the haystack end of things using `SearchQuerySet.filter(content=q)` however how do I serialize and create an api view with this queryset. I am not sure which viewset to use nor the basic logic behind what I would need to do on the rest end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

After a lot of trial and error, i have found the right combination! Here is a start.

Define a serializer: **serializers.py**

```
class DotaSearchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    text = serializers.CharField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    quality = serializers.CharField()
    type = serializers.CharField()
    rarity = serializers.CharField()
    hero = serializers.CharField()
    image = serializers.CharField()
    desc = serializers.CharField()
```

Create the view: **views.py**

```
class DotaSearchViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = DotaSearchSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        queryset = EmptySearchQuerySet()

        if request.GET.get('q') is not None:
            query = request.GET.get('q')
            queryset = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=query)

        return queryset
```

Please note you might want to clean the input and perform other security checks.

Route it: **urls.py**

```
router.register(r'search', api_views.DotaSearchViewSet, base_name='search')
```

Comment: this was extremely helpful. Thanks. Can you advise me on how to add the result count to the outputed JSON?

Comment: Have a look at Haystack for Django REST Framework: https://github.com/inonit/drf-haystack

Comment: You get your required results from getting HayStack's SearchQuerySet?
Is this the same mechanism followed when using a HayStack View(In case of Search Forms) or are any performance differences are possible?

Comment: Instead of `return queryset`, should instead do the following:
`return self.queryset.filter(pk__in=queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True))`

While returning queryset may work in some cases, this isn't how the haystack's queryset intended to be used. For example, Deep's code would fail when the permission_classes is set to DjangoModelPermissions.